# Win32::AdminMisc compilation error in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using perl 5.14.2 and when i tried to compile a perl file. It give me error "Can't locate loadable object for module Win32::AdminMisc in @INC"
While it was running fine with perl 5.6. Now i replaced perl 5.6 with 5.14.
i need compiled Win32::AdminMisc. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using ActivePerl, did you reinstall [Win32::AdminMisc](http://www.roth.net/perl/adminmisc/) for 5.14? Just adding 5.6 library paths to the 5.14's `@INC` will not work for any compiled modules.

You can try adding the Roth Consulting repository `http://www.roth.net/perl/packages` and then using `ppm install Win32::AdminMisc`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's no longer available.

I get the error "Downloading Roth Consulting repository Win32-AdminMisc PPD ... not found", when I open http://www.roth.net/perl/packages/Win32-AdminMisc.ppd in a browser it 404s, and the FTP site for roth no longer functions.